# How to use the Testing Section in Web Ide Full Stack in SAP Cloud Platform?

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

In Sap Cloud Platform Web IDE Full Stack, there seems to exist a test runner area.

I created my tests according to the tests of the template applications.

But the tests dont show up in the test runner panel.

Is there an explizit configuration area for that?
There are no information regarding that in the SAP Web IDE Full Stack manual from 23.7.2018.

[image]

Comment: Looking at this blog, it seems to be about java unit tests https://blogs.sap.com/2018/06/03/announcing-java-development-in-sap-web-ide-full-stack-part-2/. I can't seem to get it to do anything with qUnit or OPA.

Comment: @Jorg I think you are right ... Sad ...